# How can I solve troubles while debugging c code?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've been trying the whole day to debug my code using vscode. I set up the lauch.json but It's not working.
I have 3 breakpoints and I should be asked to input 3 floats but when in the Terminal it didn't prompt. Here is my code which it works fine without debugging.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c, sum;
    printf("Input three floats:");
    scanf("%f%f%f", &a, &b,&c); // %f real en coma flotante
    printf("a = %f , b = %f, c = %f", a, b,c);
    sum = a + b + c;
    printf("\nsum = %f\n\n",sum); //%f conversion a punto flotante con signo
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the lauch.json setup

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Iniciar",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        //"program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/sum_3f.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description":  "Establecer tipo de desensamblado en Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to remove "text": "-enable-pretty-printing", cause I read that it could cause trouble but It's still not working.

Here goes 2 images. I'm sorry but I'm not allowed yet to upload images so this is why there are these links:

[image: [code and terminal image]]
[image: [debug console image]]

Comment: I think the yellow bar and the arrow icon means this is the next instruction that will be executed - it hasn't executed yet. Somewhere there is a "next statement" button - click on it

Comment: You have `"stopAtEntry": false`. Do you want `true`? You should be able to single step the code as well